# How to use Sim Card on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, 18.04, lts, packaging

I am beginner with Ubuntu and I'm using 18.04 LTS version on my laptop Dell latitude E7250, which contain  port for the sim card, but I don't know how to install it and use it, I don't know even what should I provide on here,
 can anyone help me please?

**Edit**

When I looked for the propreties of  my laptop I found this 
[Dell Latitude E7250](https://www.laptopmag.com/reviews/laptops/dell-latitude-e7250) and there is nothing on Mobile Broadband, Does this mean that my laptop can't read sim cards ?

The output of

> lspci

give :

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Host Bridge -OPI (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB xHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP MEI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (3) I218-LM (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev e3)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev e3)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB EHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 03)
01:00.0 SD Host controller: O2 Micro, Inc. SD/MMC Card Reader Controller (rev 01)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 (rev 59)
```

Comment: Do you have a WWAN card?

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia and assuming s/he does, the follow on question is, does that WWAN card support the carrier s/he wants to use? IIRC most of those are Verizon-only

Comment: @AndroidDev When I was in high school there were some Dell's (in Europe) supporting different carriers.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I don't know about WWAN card, but when I search  for it I found this <https://www.laptopmag.com/reviews/laptops/dell-latitude-e7250> and there is nothing in Mobile Broadband, does that mean that I can't use the sim card on it ?

Comment: Typically all laptops of a certain model come with sim card slot, as it's cheap. All contain the wiring and antenna, but not all come with the wwan card itself. This may be bought as an addon. The output of `lspci` should tell us if you have a WWAN card.

Comment: Thank you @vidarlo I have edited the post with the output of lspci,

Comment: are you sure you arent confusing an SD card slot for a SIM slot?  your system as an sd reader which might read microsd and not sim...

Comment: @ThomasWard It's fairly common with sim slots and no WWAN card. I personally have three laptops with this feature. Two HP and one Thinkpad.

Comment: @vidarlo not saying it isnt but thats usually tablet pcs not actual laptops.  Most laptops in the past 5 years have no SIM slots, and the slots for insertion are usually about the same size as an SD card hence the inquiry

Comment: @ThomasWard It appears Latitude E7250 can be delivered with WWAN card, so I would suspect that it has a sim slot. See my answer for a link to a picture of it :)

Comment: @ThomasWard I have  the sim card slot, in the fact I have tree slots sim card (under the battery) sd card and sc card

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `lspci` output you provided, it does not look like your computer has a WWAN card. You can probably install one, but before buying, I would open the machine and verify that wiring for antenna is present. [If you look at the picture here](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Dell+Latitude+E7250+RAM+Replacement/99857) you can see a WWAN card installed at the upper left side of the computer.

Note that WWAN cards typically has to match a whitelist for that particular model. You should check which cards are delivered by default for your model. With a bit of luck, you can find it for a good price on eBay.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, does that mean that I can't use my sim card on this laptop?

Comment: I cannot see any wwan cards in the lspci output...

Comment: please excuse me, I am null on this stuffs! wwan cards  is necessar for using the sim card ?

Comment: Yes, the wwan card contains the actual radio transmitter that connects to the cellular network.

Comment: Note that you can pick up WWAN cards for 15-20$ on ebay. Installing it is half an hour, and something you can do yourself. That's however slightly out of scope of Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I know that Lenovo has "whitelists" for add on cards (just ask chili555 about WiFi cards and Lenovo) but I don't think Dell does.

Comment: @AndroidDev I know dell has whitelists on wlan cards on at least some models. I wouldn't put it past them to have whitelists on wwan as well... :)